# Putting GOPATH (or any environment variable) on a separate drive in Windows

Tags: windows, go

I have a drive that I use for non-executable stuff, and I set `%GOPATH%` to point to a directory on that drive (`D:\go\path`). However, I can't simply type

```
cd %GOPATH%
```

from the C:\ drive and navigate there. I need to type

```
cd /c d:\go\path
```

Will the go linker/compiler/assembler/other stuff still function the same way?

Comment: Go tools do not use Windows built in command `cd`. So everything should work as expected. Why not give it a try and see yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior on the command line is solely cd's fault. If you would write out the whole gopath string, you would get exactly the same behaviour. As go does (have to) make the drive/folder distinction on it's own while processing the path, everything will work just fine.